# How can I make frosting without powdered sugar

Tags: sugar, icing

Milk Frosting. 
1 and a 1/2 Cup Sugar, 1/2 Cup milk, 1 tsp Butter.
Put in a saucepan stirring constantly until it begins to boil.
Let boil with out stirring, until a few drops tested in cold water form a soft ball.  Remove from heat.
Stir in 1 tsp of vanilla extract, then beat until it becomes a spreadable consistancy. 
If frosting becomes too stiff to spread, put in a double boiler over boiling water (a bowl on a pot of boiling water will work) it will melt, then beat again.

Comment: Is this a question and answer?  If not, what are you trying to ask about this recipe?

Comment: See also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24934/what-kinds-of-frostings-have-a-lighter-texture

Comment: As far as I can understand the question, it is that you want to make the recipe but have no powdered sugar available. Therefore closing as a duplicate. If you meant to ask something else, please edit the question text and flag for reopening.